# What does Fatou's lemma say about these $f_j$?

Tags: measure-theory

I know that Fatou's lemma states that if $\{f_j\}_{j\geq 1}$ is a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions and $f_j(x)\longrightarrow f(x)$ almost everywhere on a set E, then
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_E f\leq \liminf\int\limits_E f_j\notag
\end{eqnarray}

**Now I have this question**: Consider $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with Lebesgue measure. For $j=1,2,\cdots,$ let
\begin{eqnarray}
f_j(x)=\begin{cases}1+\sin jx & \mathrm{if}~~ -\pi \leq x\leq \pi \\0 & \mathrm{if}~ ~ x<- \pi \\ 0 & \mathrm{if}~~  x> \pi. \end{cases}\notag
\end{eqnarray}
What does Fatou's lemma say about these $f_j$?

Can somebody assist me here please. I don't know how to begin.

Comment: I think you should rather use the version $\int\liminf f_n\le \liminf\int f_n$. And then, calculate $\int f_j$ and see what it is.

Comment: I don't see how the version of FL you cite says much, since the functions fo not converge pointwise. In fact the statement I learned as Fatou's Lemma is this: If $(f_n)$ is _any_ sequence of non-negatiive measurable functions  then $\int\liminf f_n\le\liminf \int f_n$.

Comment: So my worry is that even with this suggested version of Fatou's lemma. How do I answer the above question? I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

(This is essentially the same as the first comment on the question.)

Let $f = \liminf_{j} f_{j}$. Then by Fatou's lemma
$$
\int f \leq \lim_{j} \int f_{j}.
$$
You can easily calculate $\int f_{j}$ as well as the right-hand side above. For the left-hand side, you need to figure out what $f$ is. But without doing that, you know an upper bound on $\int f$ from the inequality above, and you can show certain properties of $f$. For example, $f$ cannot be equal to $2$ a.e. on $(-\pi,\pi)$.